# MySQL Insert Unique Value

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a MySQL Table that has a column that will `AUTO_INCREMENT`, another to store user-submitted data, and another column that defaults to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

My `INSERT` query is:

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO `UserData` (`user_data`) VALUES(?)");
$query->bind_param('s', $commentdata);
$query->execute();
```

However it is still inserting the duplicate values (if a user clicks submit multiple times). What is the best way to prevent this?

Comment: And the table def is?

Comment: If you let the user insert whatever value he wants , you will get duplicate errors !. do you mean you want to generate random unique value for every click ?

Comment: From the view of "user experience" the "best way" would be not to use `IGNORE` but to check if the entry already exists in the DB every time before insertion and tell the user if it's the case.

Comment: Your `bind_param` call is wrong. `sss` means there are 3 parameters being bound, but you only have 1 parameter in the query.

Comment: @Barmar: You are correct. Forgot to remove my other table values when I was generalizing this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL will not create duplicate auto increment ids (unless you have a very badly configured cluster) so presumably the duplicates you refer to are in a different attribute - you've only told us about user_data.

If you don't want duplicates in there then add a unique index on the column. You should also add error handling to deal with failures when the situation arises and remove the 'IGNORE'.

However you also need to think about your controlling logic (this hints that you probably have csrf vulnerabilities) and your user interface (why are you allowing users to submit the same form twice?)

Comment: It may have been users who double clicked the submit button.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `UserData` (`post_num`, `user_data`)
SELECT ?, ? FROM `UserData`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `UserData` WHERE `post_num`= ? AND `user_data`=?
) LIMIT 1
```

Then I do `$query->bind_param('isis', $post_number, $comment, $post_number, $comment);` to bind the values.

This will check to make sure there are no duplicate comments on a post.

Note that my actual example inserts more information such as the user information and I check to make sure there are no duplicate comments from that certain user on a specific post.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to prevent duplicate values in a MySQL table is for the table definition to use the `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY` constraint. See [the documentation for table creation syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html).

You may also want the value to be a `KEY` if you plan on performing lookups using that value.